# Convert PDF to image in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, image, pdf

I want to convert PDF pages to images and show them in `<img/>`. I've searched a lot and found many libraries but they didn't work in `typescript`.
I've installed `pdf-img-convert`, `pdfjs-dist`, and 'react-pdf-to-image'. None of them worked. The first two show errors like the below message.

> util.js:511 Uncaught TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function

I am confused and don't know if I can use these libraries in `typescript` or are not appropriate. And if I can't use them in `typescript`, which library is good for me?

I would appreciate it if you give me a sample or link which used in `typescript`.

Comment: Try using [pdf2image](https://github.com/yakovmeister/pdf2image) by Yakovmeister, it is written using typescript so it should work.

Comment: The LEADTOOLS [PDF](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/pdf) Library can convert and load PDF files as images. As an example, you can find the viewer demo [here](https://demo.leadtools.com/JavaScript/Viewer). For using this toolkit in TypeScript, see the tutorial [here](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/tutorials/html5-ts-package-and-run-html5-examples-with-typescript.html). You can also download a [free evaluation](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads) should you want try this yourself. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)